# Karma + Jasmine + fdescribe

Tags: karma-jasmine

When I attempt to use fdescribe I receive the error "^ 'fdescribe' is not defined.".

I have verified that I am using Jasmin 2.3 with the following:

```
  describe('Test to print out jasmine version', function() {
    it('prints jasmine version', function() {
        console.log('jasmine-version:');
        console.log(jasmine.version || (jasmine.getEnv().versionString && jasmine.getEnv().versionString()));
    });
});
```

Also I am using "karma": "0.13.19" and "karma-jasmine": "0.3.4".

Any ideas on why I can't use fdescribe or fit?

Answer (score 2):

It could be the version. Try using `ddescribe` and `iit` instead.